# Generating temp.proto file from temp_pb2.py file

Tags: python, xml, protocol-buffers

The protocol buffer compiler produces Python output when invoked with the --python_out= command-line flag. The parameter to the --python_out= option is the directory where you want the compiler to write your Python output. The compiler creates a .py file for each .proto file input.

But can we generate the same source file from temp_pb2.py?